# How to keep edittexts values after calling another activity than back

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have **Activity A** with some `edittexts`  and a `button`.After user populates `edittextsin` **Activity A**.Click the `button` than calling **Activity B** ( `Listview`). User click on listitem and come to back **Activity A**. My problem is when i come back to **Activity A** all `edittexts` are empty. How i can save `edittexts` values. Tyvm

```
Activity A calls Activity B
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HayvanKartiList.class);
                intent.putExtra("activityname",BuzagiKayitActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ciftlikoid", ciflikoid);
                startActivity(intent);

Activity B calls Activity A 
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  BuzagiKayitActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("kupeno", selItem.getKupeNo().toString());
            i.putExtra("hayvanoid", selItem.getOid().toString());
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: did you call finish() in your Activity A when you make Intent to Activity B?

Comment: yea ? shouldnt I ?

Comment: yep if you want to save your values in editText , try it and tell me if is corrrect

Comment: ok. i removed the finish() thing and still edittext values gone.

Comment: when you click ont list view item are you make new Intent from Activity B to Activity A ?

Comment: just finish activity b in activity b and don't start activity A again

Comment: can you post your two Activities here please.

Comment: if i call just finish activity b edittexts  values still there but if i dont start activity how  pass parameter from Activity B to A ( activity b has a listview, i have to pass on listviews clicked item)

Comment: Use static variables in A. Modify them in B (`A.myVar = myValue;`). Finish B. EASY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call **Actvity A** from **Actvity B**.Just Call OnBackPressed use the below code to get result from **Actvity B**

**In Activity A**

```
//Activity A calls Activity B
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HayvanKartiList.class);
                intent.putExtra("activityname",BuzagiKayitActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ciftlikoid", ciflikoid);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
       // parse your returned values from data intent here
    }
  }
```

**In Activity B**

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   getIntent().putExtra("kupeno", selItem.getKupeNo().toString());
   getIntent().putExtra("hayvanoid", selItem.getOid().toString());
   this.setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

To Call Activity A From Actvity B Call OnBackPressed

```
private void onItemClick(){
  onBackPressed();
}
```