# Android setActivtyForResult get result back to first activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have FirstActivity, which calls SecondActivity via Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("param1","aaa");
extras.putString("param2","bbb");
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

After SecondActivity finish, I want the SecondActivity sends some variables to the FirstActivity. Then I call finsih() so it will back to the FirstActivity. How to make the SecondActivity send variables and get the result in FirstActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Just make another `Intent` in you `SecondActivity`
    First get Variables from `FirstActivity`

```
  Bundle extras = getArguments();
     String extra1 = extras.getString("param1");
     String extra2 = extras.getString("param2");
```

Then make intent to `FirstActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("param1","aaa");
intent.putExtra("param2","bbb");
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

I hope that im undestand correct your problem.

Comment: The problem is it will call onCreate method  on the FirstActivity. I don't wont to call onCreate again

Comment: @MeGoodGuy i think he get notification from your answer ... no need to spam my answer ok ???!!

Comment: Yeah sorry. But dont answer if u dont know -_-

Comment: First i answer the way i undestend because the question isnt clear enought what he what to achive... Second your answer isnt clear enought too what you told him copy one url from google documentation and its ok ? dont make me to give you stack-overflow-conditions "how to answer the questions", because you are for minus right now!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easily.

Use startActivityForResult, giving an integer to identify the Activity,
Then on your FirstActivity u override the onActivityResult method.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my answer to a similar question at the below link

[How to keep edittexts values after calling another activity than back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196074/how-to-keep-edittexts-values-after-calling-another-activity-than-back/36196705?noredirect=1#comment60028207_36196705)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample and alter it based on your needs.

Add an override onActivityResult on the First Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0) //The request code you use on statActivityForResult (Any integer value)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            String stringFromSecondActivity = data.getExtras().getString("Key");
        }
    }
}
```

Start the second activity just like what you posted

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("param1","aaa");
extras.putString("param2","bbb");
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0); //This is the request code to check on onActivityResult when you retrieve values from the SecondActivity after finishing it.
```

On your second Activity, before finishing it, you should get the intent and add some extras to it.

```
getIntent().putExtra("Key", "theStringForTheFirstActivity");
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
finish();
```

When the second Activity is finished, it will automatically execute your onActivityResult on your first Activity and there you can get the values you need from the second Activity.